# Trino python client sending ABANDONED_QUERY while looping on cursor.fetchone()

Tags: python, hive, trino

I've got a script i want to keep low on memory, so I'm looping over a `cursor.fetchone()` call and processing each row individually.

But after about 30 minutes, it exits with

> TrinoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=ABANDONED_QUERY, message=... Query results have not been accessed since 2023-10-13T17:10:23.546Z: currentTime 2023-10-13T17:15:23.774Z"

Whats more interesting is the timestamp for "accessed since" is actually when I *started* the script!

So somewhere along the line, the client is processing this error but waiting to spit it out?
Let me know if anyone can tell what's going on here. Very curious behavior

tried:

- I tried looping over the contents of a DB table with the trino python client cursor.fetchone() and was successful for 30 minutes,
- expecting to reach the end of the table and exit the program normally,
- but what actually happened was that I received an error for having not accessed the query within 5 minutes of the start of the program.

Comment: It sounds like python is buffering some or all of the response when you fetch the first row, so it's not going back to the database for each row. So as far as the database is concerned, you've been idle that whole time.

Comment: Check the `trino` documentation to see if there's a way to make it unbuffered.

Comment: Youre right @Barmar i just confirmed by running over each row without any processing and the memory usage was about 32MB throughout and it got all the way to the end. still struggling to find docs on how to set the buffer size in the python client though